# DevExpress VB report Issues

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have a problem that i can't display a data from my bindingsource. I need to display a datas from two bindingsources that are filled with datas from db tables that are connected with FK. I put the object datas that i need to display but there are empty.

Can samebody tell how to fix this problem?

Comment: what kind of database is it? Are you using the vb.net way with datasets and binding sources rather than just querieing the database?

Comment: Please provide us with some code to identify your specific problem.